# Parse date value from hyperlink to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar API. Above the calendar I have important dates in a summary table. I want to be able to click on the date and for the calendar to open that month automatically. So far I have:

Basically I need to replace the '2013-05-29' in the javascript with the PHP variable $date1 but have no idea how I would parse this without using $POST and reloading the page.

Thanks in advance!

```
function seeDate() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', '2013-05-29' )
}


<td><a href="javascript:seeDate()"><?php echo $date1 ." - ". $date2; ?></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
function seeDate(date) {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )
}


<td><a href="javascript:seeDate('<?=$date1 ?>')"><?php echo $date1 ." - ". $date2; ?></a></td>
```